# removeClass or toggleClass with transitions?

Tags: jquery, addclass, transition, removeclass

I have a nice little jquery script to expand a button, and am pushing down content below it when it opens (just by doing addClass()). This all works fine. When I close the button, I wanted to removeClass() (to move the content back up), but that's not working, the class, 'open' stays on the element-- I have seen a lot of stuff out there saying removeClass has caused issues for people.

toggleClass got me a little closer to where I want to be, but the transition back up is very abrupt. Is there any way to add a CSS transition when using toggleClass???

Here's my code with just the add/removeClass option...I  am using jquery 1.11.3

```
    <script>
            $('#burger').click(function() {
                  $(this).toggleClass('expanded').siblings('div').slideToggle();
                $('#logo').addClass('open').slideToggle;


            });

      $('#burger.expanded').click(function(){

     $('#logo').removeClass('open');

      });
```

Comment: You talk about `CSS transition` but nothing in your posted code is relevant to it. That's said, adding/removing class which hanlde some CSS transition isn't an issue usually. Provide sample replicating your issue

Comment: Read up on [slidetoggle](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_slidetoggle.asp).

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem is that you have ...s('open').slideToggle;, so you are not calling the function? You should have slideToggle(), not just slideToggle.

Comment: Looks like just a typo in question